# Docker push needs user name to push to hub

Tags: python, docker, docker-image

I am trying to push to docker but it says it says that authorisation is needed. I know to solve this problem i am meant to add my user name before the docker push.
I have built a docker image using :

```
docker build -t registry.heroku.com/myapp/web .
```

This build an image in my docker hub.
I ensure that i am logged into my docker and also ensure that i have a heroku container built and logged in.

```
heroku login
heroku container: login
```

Then when i try to do a docker push:

```
docker push myname/registry.heroku.com/myapp/web
```

i then get an error saying: `An image does not exist locally with the tag: myname/registry.heroku.com/myapp/web`

When I do `docker images` then it comes up with the image i created `registry.heroku.com/myapp/web`

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: If you are allowed to push to `registry.heroku.com` (that `docker login` succeeded) then you `docker push registry.heroku.com/myapp/web`, with the same name you tagged the image with; there's no need to duplicate your user name at the beginning of it.

Comment: "I know to solve this problem i am meant to add my user name before the docker push." -- that seems to contradict the error message you're getting. I'd question that.

Answer (score 1):

You have built **registry.heroku.com/myapp/web** image and trying to push **myname/registry.heroku.com/myapp/web** which definitely doesn't exist.

- You need to push the image with the same name that you have built.
- Heroku does not accept images with **myname/registry.heroku.com/myapp/web**. It should be **registry.heroku.com/myapp/web**
- So try pushing the image (It is **correct**)

  ```
  docker push registry.heroku.com/myapp/web
  ```
- **myname/registry.heroku.com/myapp/web** (It is **Incorrect**)

  - login to heroku cli

    ```
    heroku container:login
    ```
  - login to Heroku registry with docker and Heroku's auth token

    ```
    docker login --username=_ --password=$(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com
    ```
  - push the image

    ```
    docker push registry.heroku.com/myapp/web
    ```

Follow [This Heroku Document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) on pushing images

Comment: thanks for the answer. However when i do this i get an error that says `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

Comment: @Kitchen If you haven't installed the Heroku cli please install and do the following commands. Login to Heroku  `heroku container:login`. Login to Heroku container registry with docker and Heroku's auth token `docker login --username=_ --password=$(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com`. Push the image `docker push registry.heroku.com/myapp/web`